# Saben porque mi código puede estar regresando siempre false?

Tags: php, sql, html5, login

Estoy creando un inicio de sesión y la contraseña es hash cuando se registran pero al momento de iniciar sesión tenía el problema de que aceptaba cualquier contraseña, después logré corregirlo pero ahora no acepta ninguna contraseña, ya hice todo, verifique el código, la base de datos, depuré el código y aún no he podido solucionar, en la depuración me di cuenta que es en el password_verify pero no sé cómo solucionarlo

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    require("conexion.php");

    try {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo = :correo";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':correo', $email);
        $stmt->execute();

        $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if ($user) {
            if (password_verify($password, $user['contraseña'])) {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['usuario_id'] = $user['user_id']; 
                header("Location: index.php"); 
                exit();
            } else {

                echo "Contraseña incorrecta. Acceso denegado.";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Correo no encontrado. Acceso denegado.";
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error en la conexión o inicio de sesión: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

[image: imagen de la estructura de mi base de datos]

Si necesitan más información se las proporcionaré gracias

Comment: `$user['contraseña'] != $user['password']`

Comment: Si perdón igual si que ponga password no funciona, y ese código es porque edite la base de datos antes de hacer la pregunta

Comment: Observa que tu columna en la tabla `usuarios` se llama **`password`**, no se llama `contraseña` **y me alegro por ello**, porque deberías evitar nombres de tablas/columnas con `ñ`, acentos o carácteres especiales. Simplemente cambia el código así: **`if (password_verify($password, $user['password'])) {`**. Tu error está aquí: `$user['contraseña']`. Para `$user`  debes usar el nombre correcto de la columna cuyo dato quieres obtener. Si, como dices, usaste `password_hash`  **al momento de hacer el `INSERT`** debería funcionar si estás pasando la contraseña correcta, claro está.

Comment: Okay ahora regrese al primer problema, el código acepta cualquier contraseña, creo que terminaré creando todo desde cero si no encuentro una solución hoy

Comment: Es que entre tantos cambios ya no se sabe que es lo que tienes (como se llama la tabla realmente, como se llaman las columnas, etc). No hace falta que pongas capturas de pantalla. En MySQL ejecuta un `SHOW CREATE TABLE usuarios;` Pega el resultado en la pregunta, así como el código PHP como lo tengas. Confírmanos también si usas `password_hash` al momento de insertar y dinos qué muestra un `var_dump($_POST);` Que la cosa no es tan complicada, solo aprende a depurar tu código. Y en la pregunta a mostrar cada parte relevante del problema en su estado real.